# sql declaration structure how does it run in php?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'am a newbe in SQL and PHP and execute my SQL like this:

```
$query  = 'SELECT session, id FROM AnalysePageview WHERE session="'.$sessionID.'"ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1';                 
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

now I have seen in this forum something like this:

```
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(description) 
                    from customerrewards
                    group by description, typeid
                    order by typeid
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT name,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select c.name,
                  cr.description,
                  r.typeid
                from customers c
                left join rewards r
                  on c.id = r.customerid
                left join customerrewards cr
                  on r.typeid = cr.typeid
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                count(typeid)
                for description in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

if I put this in a $query="DECLARE @cols ... I will get an error.

How can I use this declarations in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it is not possible to run this SQL.

See [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html) for more details:

> DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement
>   and must be at its start, before any other statements.

Comment: does it mean no pivot-tables with mysqli_query

Comment: It seems that complex statements in MySQL can be used only within procedures/functions